# How to prove $C=2πr$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Everybody know this formula,but why the relation between $C$ and $r$ is linear relation? Not $C=2πr^{0.99}$ or $C=2πr^{1.01}$how to prove it,what axiom is it based on?

Comment: Well the statement $(\exists \pi \in \mathbb{R}, \forall C \in \text{ Circles })\,C_{circumfrence} = 2\pi C_{radius}$ follows from basic understanding of how things scale in 2 dimensions (proportionality).  This may as well be used to simply define $\pi$.

Comment: Strange question for one of the greatest geometers of the 20th century to be asking. :)

Answer (score 1):

As the rectification of the circle ultimately relies on triangulation, this follows from the corresponding proportionality for triangles, hence ultimately from the intercept theorem (not a single axiom).